# SQLSTATE[28000][1045]Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'(using pass:YES)(SQL:select*from`categories`where(`status`=1)and(`is_home`=1))

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'iftikha3_interior'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select *
> from `categories` where (`status` = 1) and (`is_home` = 1))

I can't under stand help me in this solution.

this is a website i can open it

Comment: Which part of `Access denied` are you struggling with? And did you google the error message, to try to understand it more? Basically you either gave the wrong username/password combination for the mysql user, or you did not give that user permission to access the requested database.

Comment: It means that user 'iftikha3_interior' doesn't have access to perform that query OR maybe you have entered the wrong username and password in your .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .env file where you may provided some incorrect information. Specially check following environment variables value.

DB_CONNECTION,
DB_HOST,
DB_PORT,
DB_DATABASE,
DB_USERNAME,
DB_PASSWORD

Provide correct information as environment variables value. I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks...